# Tips for finding and identifying wiring diagrams

Tags: electrical

Many of the electrical questions asked on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair could be much more easily and authoritatively answered with access to the wiring diagrams for the car in question.

I've had *very* mixed results searching online for wiring diagrams. What I've been doing is to search on something like:

> <make> <model> <year> wiring diagram

For example:

> audi a5 2012 wiring diagram

Sometimes I luck out, but often the results will be a hodgepodge of related and unrelated schematics. Any suggestions on how to improve the results or even on how to quickly determine if a result is actually for the car in question?

Also, I'd be interested in ideas for how to find the right section of the wiring diagram. For VW (at least) the wiring diagram spans many pages of the service manual, so it would be nice to have strategies for getting to the specific page that covers the circuit of interest.

Comment: Get an Alldata subscription. That would fulfill both questions.

Comment: @vini_i - Alldata looks great if you can justify the cost (it appears to be about $170/month for a subscription), the DIY subscription is very reasonable ($30/year or $45 for 5 years for the first vehicle, $17/year and $30/5-years for additional vehicles), but it is limited to specific vehicles (year, make, model, and engine) so it isn't very practical in the case of wanting to be able to help with questions about arbitrary vehicles.

Comment: What your looking for is a pipe dream. Free repair info is spotty or just not available on line without subscribing to something like Alldata.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, wiring diagrams are not public domain. Wiring diagrams for cars five years and newer will usually be found in the specific shop manuals. Others for that particular car would be in their respective manuals.(Chilton, Haynes.Mitchell...etc)

In order for everyone to give a specific location for a section of the wiring diagram, they would have to all be using the same manual.

Even though this doesn't help, about the only way to access a wiring diagram, at this time, is to get the book.(Library ?)

Alldata is also an option.

It seems like the VW manual should point you to the correct section.

//Some of this should have been in the comments section, there is actually not a concrete answer for this question, more of pointing in the right direction.//